# Pass variable in Ansible inventory and call with ansible playbook command

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory file which contains this information:

```
Test-server ansible_host=10.0.0.8 ansible_user=root
```

ansible playbook to create a file in tmp directory:

```
- hosts: '{{ is_host }}'
  tasks:
    - name: Creating yml file in tmp directory
      file:
        path: "/tmp/ansible-playbook.yml"
        state: touch
```

I can execute this playbook with the command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory tmp-file.yml --extra-vars "is_host=xyz-server"
```

I want this `Test-server` to be set as variable in inventory (INI) file, something like this:

```
{{is_host}} ansible_host=10.0.0.8 ansible_user=root
```

...and pass the value in ansible-playbook command.

Actually, I am using Azure devops to grab the server's host name dynamically from pipeline task and want to assign the value in Ansible inventory. When I use Host list in Ansible task it grabs the value and assign to host as below:
[image: host-list-ansible-task]

...but when I select `Inventory Location` as File then it does not pick host value from previous.
[image: file-as-inventory-location]

... that's why I am looking a way to pass `hostname` as variable in inventory file which I can use anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Either with ini or yaml format, Ansible inventories would not accept Jinja syntax defining target addresses or hostnames.

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Maybe consider generating that inventory file before applying your playbook?

Comment: Thank you for the response @SYN . I got it working in another way. Now, I'm replacing inventory file content using replace module and with the help of regexp. Since I've just one entry in that inventory file like hostname and it's IP address so it replaces file content with azure pipeline variable.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan can you elaborate or share documentation on how you made it work ? I'm having the same issue. I'd like to pass the a name to my inventory file to get only one specific vm in that group.